# jPlayer playlist no toggle from ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

Maybe my question title maybe wrong and i can't try too big as title, but the thing is i am trying to add song in playlist from ajax request.

in jplayer i created playlist and set songs using setPlaylist function and this works fine. problem is when i click on album button it start playing song and i want it to pause.

This is my song function :

```
AddSongToPlaylist(songs) {    
    songs.filter((song) => {
         self.MySong.addSong(song);
         self.MySong.setUser(song.user_id);
         myplayer.setPlaylist(self.MySong.getSongList());
    });
}
```

And on button i did this : AddSongToPlaylist(song_object)

My song is object class that adds songs to songList and from there i pick songs using .getSongList

But i don't think there will be any issue but there could be solution where i can run `AddSongToPlaylist(song_object)` function one time only when no matched song added to list.

Please let me know if anyone tried this.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to answer properly without more detail. What function(s) does clicking on the album button call? What are the jPlaylist options that you specified?

The `setPlaylist` function for jPlaylist automatically plays the media **if** you have the `autoplay` option set to true on your playlist options.

If this isn't the case then provide more details.